# Find the number of distinct ways of writing '1' as a sum of fractions, each with '1' as numerator and a power of '2' as denominator

Tags: math, dynamic-programming, integer-arithmetic

I am given a number `n` and I have to find the number of **distinct** ways of writing the number `1` as a sum of `n` fractions, where each fraction has the following format:

- The numerator is always 1.
- The denominator is a power of 2 (for example 2^1, 2^2, etc).

Two methods of writing `1` as a sum of such fractions are NOT distinct if they contain the same fractions. For example, let's say `n=4`. One way of writing `1` as a sum of `4` fractions would be the following: `1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/8`. But writing it as `1/8 + 1/4 + 1/2 + 1/8` is considered the same(because it contains the exact same fractions, only the order changed) and therefore NOT distinct when compared to the first way of writing. So for `n=4` there would only be two ways of writing `1` as a sum of 4 fractions. The first would be `1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/8`(the one mentioned above) and the second would be `1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4`. So the result would be `2`. The boundaries of `n` are : `2 <= n <= 2000`.

I wrote the first few on paper (for `n=2`, for `n=3`, for `n=4` and a few more) and I thought that the results are part of the Fibonacci sequence so that's what I tried but when I sent the source on the site it said that it is wrong. I have a feeling that I have to use dynamic programming but I am not sure how to implement it. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "*I have a feeling that I have to use dynamic programming*" - why? Also - what have you *actually* tried? I see no code

Comment: @Fureeish I already said I tried to use the Fibonacci sequence and extract the answer from the sequence, but that proved to be wrong. What's the point of posting code that's wrong? Other than that I haven't tried anything else because I don't know how to solve the problem. I need an idea. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: "*What's the point of posting code that's wrong?*" - so we can help you inspect what's wrong with the code. Paste your code, explain the thought process and then we will be able to see your possible error in the implementation. Of course unless you proved that your algorithm and the entire idea is incorrect. What's more, Stack Overflow is not a place where people will figure out your algorithms for you. This is a place for specific programming questions. Not a place for "any ideas about how to start solving this problem?" type of questions.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start by playing a few rounds of [2048](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(video_game)). But don't blame me if you can't stop.

Your list of summands has a smallest one, 2<sup>−*k*</sup>. You can scale your whole sum by 2<sup>*k*</sup> to make all numbers integers, and in fact powers of two. This might make thinking about the problem easier. Now think about the sum as an operation on binary numbers, e.g.

```
   0100
   0100
   0100
   0010
   0001
+  0001
= 10000
```

Start adding the lowest integers. There have to be two of them. Otherwise you couldn't zero the last bit. An exception to this rule if *n*=1, i.e. you only have one summand. So you can add the two smallest numbers to obtain one that's twice as big. Then continue until you reach a single number. You could do the same with binary fractions to avoid the scaling step, if you want.

So an important invariant here is that you can add terms in such a way that they remain negative powers of two. The sequence of additions will form a binary tree, with the value of the node indicated by the depth: the root has 1, the next level 1/2, the next 1/4 and so on. Each node is either a leaf with zero children or an inner node with two children. You are interested in binary trees with *n* leaves, but consider trees equal if they have the same number of leaves in each level.

To start thinking recursively, how do you go from a tree with *n* leaves to one with *n+1* leaves? You add a pair of children to an existing leaf. Let's write some python code.

```python
def expansions(v):
    for i in range(len(v) - 1):
        if v[i]:
            yield tuple(x - 1 if j == i else x + 2 if j == i + 1 else x
                        for j, x in enumerate(v))
    yield v[:-1] + (v[-1] - 1, 2)  # start a new level

s = set([(1,)])  # start with a bare root
for n in range(1, 21):
    print("{:4d}: {:10d}".format(n, len(s)))
    s = set(y for x in s for y in expansions(x))
```

Then go to http://oeis.org/ and enter the sequence you got the hard way. The Search will list one hit, [A002572](http://oeis.org/A002572), which is described as

> Number of partitions of 1 into n powers of 1/2

Bingo. Unfortunately it doesn't come with a closed formula. But there is a list of values precomputed for n=2000. So here is a shell script to determine the result for any given *n* by looking up in that:

```shell
wget -qO- 'http://oeis.org/A002572/b002572.txt' | tail -n+${n:?} | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

If you want a more serious answer, I suggest you follow the references cited on OEIS. Or try to make sense of that function `v` which is described as

> *v*(*c*, *d*) is the number of partitions of *d* into positive integers of the form *d* = *c* + *c*<sub>1</sub> + *c*<sub>2</sub> + … + *c*<sub>*n*</sub>, where *c*<sub>1</sub> ≤ 2 *c*, *c*<sub>*i*+1</sub> ≤ 2 *c*<sub>*i*</sub>.

and which is used for some magic dynamic programming in Mathematica, Maple and Pari.

So where is the connection? To answer that, switch from considering the leaf nodes to considering the inner nodes instead. If you have *n* leaf nodes, then you have *d*=*n*−1 inner nodes. *v*(1,*d*) is counting ways to arrange these inner nodes, by partitioning the number of inner nodes according to layer. You need one inner node at the root, unless you have *n*=1 which is not well covered by this consideration. And each subsequent layer can have at least zero inner nodes, and at most twice the number of inner nodes from the layer before.

Barring corner cases, the basic recursion is

```
v(c, d) = sum(v(i, d-c) for i=1..2*c)
```

because if *d*=*c*+*c*<sub>1</sub>+*c*<sub>2</sub>+…+*c*<sub>*m*</sub> then this corresponds to *d*−*c*=*c*<sub>1</sub>+*c*<sub>2</sub>+…+*c*<sub>*m*</sub> so you need ways to partition `d-c`, with `i`=*c*<sub>1</sub> is between 0 and 2 *c*. This can be used for a nice dynamic programming implementation. Here are all the values you need to compute up to *d*=20 i.e. *n*=21:

```
v(c,d)   c=1   c=2   c=3   c=4   c=5   c=6   c=7   c=8   c=9
 d= 1:     1
 d= 2:     1     1
 d= 3:     2     1     1
 d= 4:     3     2     1     1
 d= 5:     5     4     2     1     1
 d= 6:     9     7     4     2     1     1
 d= 7:    16    12     7     4     2     1     1
 d= 8:    28    22    13     7     4     2     1     1
 d= 9:    50    39    24    13     7     4     2     1     1
 d=10:    89    70    42    24    13     7     4     2
 d=11:   159   126    76    43    24    13     7     4
 d=12:   285   225   137    78    43    24    13     7
 d=13:   510   404   245   140    78    43    24    13
 d=14:   914   725   441   251   141    78
 d=15:  1639  1299   792   452
 d=16:  2938  2331  1420   812
 d=17:  5269  4182  2550  1457
 d=18:  9451  7501
 d=19: 16952 13458
 d=20: 30410
```